# Password history restrictions are written to in system-auth(-ac), but not password-auth(-ac). Why, when every other policy gets written to both?

Tags: linux, security, pam

According to [this STIG](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_7/2017-12-14/finding/V-71933), password history is entered into `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, but not `/etc/pam.d/password-auth`.  Other policies, for example, [account lockouts](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_7/2017-12-14/finding/V-71945) are applied to both files.

Why isn't the password history entered into both, or is this just a typo in the STIG?  (Hard to believe that second, but it happens.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `password-auth` and `system-auth` files are not directly used by any process or service. Instead, they are pulled into other PAM configuration files using the `include` directive. The only thing that really cares about password history on a default installation is the `passwd` command. It has its own PAM module, and it only pulls in `system-auth`:

```
[root@rhel7 ~]# grep include /etc/pam.d/passwd
auth       include      system-auth
account    include      system-auth
```

Account lockouts are recommended for both because services like `sshd` pull in `password-auth` instead. On the RHEL 7 system I'm looking at right now, `system-auth` is mostly pulled into PAM files for things the user would interact with directly (login, password changes, `su` and `sudo`, etc.), while `password-auth` is pulled in by running daemons like `sshd` and `crond`.

You can add the password history setting to `pam_unix.so` in `password-auth` for consistency, if you want to. It won't harm anything, but neither will it do anything useful.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  So `sshd`/`crond` don't need it because the history is only ever called when changing the password, which will only be happening at the shell.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: Correct, mostly. You only care about old passwords when you need to compare them to a new one you want to use. The STIG correctly modifies the only file that is needed in order to apply this policy to invocations of the `passwd` command. It's not limited to just the shell, though, since you could call `passwd` from a script through non-interactive automation if you wanted to.